# I want to make a staff user by default

Tags: python, django

I am making a library system with signup pages (admin and user), so when I make an admin user I want to make it in staff, so how can I use (is_staff)?

this is my registration function...

```
def register(request):
    form = CreateUserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')

            messages.success(request, 'Account created successfully')
            return redirect(loginpage)

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'pages/register.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alter the `.instance` wrapped in the form before saving it to the database:

```
def register(request):
    form = CreateUserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.is_staff = True
            user = form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')

            messages.success(request, 'Account created successfully')
            return redirect(loginpage)

    return render(request, 'pages/register.html', {'form':form})
```